# Can't Download Apps on Restricted Automobile Android

Tags: google-play-store, unknown-sources

I just got a new Renault Fluence (basically a Megane Coupe) with an Android entertainment system. It seems to be basically the Kaier System http://www.szkaier.com/show_imgnews.asp?id=537 modified by the local importer and it includes a sim card with WAZE for navigation.

The problem is that I'd like to install a few more apps. There is (naturally) no Google Play Store, installation of unknown sources is unchecked and requires a (numeric) password, ES file explorer is installed but any app that offer to let me register with my Google account is automatically blocked by redirecting to Waze (probably some trick to make sure we don't download apps using our Google accounts.

Simple attempts at guessing the "unknown sources" (numeric) password were unsuccessful.
It seems that I can connect the wifi to any wifi source. (Connection to the sim card is via wifi for some odd reason.)
I have no access to any buttons on the phone (without taking the dash apart) and the one full size USB seems to be open for music only.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks